# Resistors in parallel - Written description of a circuit - drawing needed

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance

I can't visualise what this circuit looks like from the description

> Three identical resistors are connected across a potential difference V so that one of them is in parallel with the other two which are connected in series.

I am guessing it looks like this . . . . (there is no diagram given in the question)

[image]

Would I be right in assuming this?

The rest of the question depends getting this part right.

The rest of the question is as follows . ...

> The power dissipated through the first one , compared to the power dissipated by each of the other two , is approximately..
>
> **A** the same,
> **B** half as much,
> **C** twice as much,
> **D** four times as much,

The answer is apparently D, which makes me think my drawing can't be correct.

Any help?

Comment: That's definitely right.

Comment: Indeed, both the circuit and D are right. Note that the power dissipated is $RI^2$.

Comment: Ok, that's all I wanted to know. I'll go figure out why now. I'll be back if I get stuck. Cheers.

Comment: Ok, I'm still stuck. One more clue please? Not asking for an answer, just a hint.

Comment: Power dissipated is $V^2\over{R}$. And, the two resistors in series dissipate equal amounts of power.

Comment: I was stupidly not taking into account that Pd across each one of the two resistors in series is half of that across the one that is in parallel to them.

Comment: Why do people bother to respond to a question if they then go and downvote it as off topic afterwards?

Comment: It was a genuine question, Norbert, not a complaint. I'm grateful for the help. I can see from the tone of your reaction that you may have taken it badly. Also, I thought it was clear I wasn't looking for an answer, but rather a nudge in the right direction. (I'm not some kid trying to get his homework done by someone else).

Comment: Although I now see why It was flagged, having read the rules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Yes**, your drawing correctly illustrates what the question describes.

Since the question later refers to the *first one* and *the other two*, it is reasonable to assume the author is referring to the resistor with $V$ across it and the two in series, respectively.

In case it still isn't clear, the power dissipated in any one of those resistors is given by

$$P=I^2R,$$

where $R$ is the same for the all resistors but $I$ is different for the two "branches".  Once you find the lone resistor has twice the current going through it, you can see why it has four times the power dissipation.